# Scala: Printing fields and values of given class

Tags: scala, reflection, traits

So I wrote a Debug trait that is meant to print fields and values that are stored in a class.

```
class Point(xv: Int, yv: Int) extends Debug {
var x: Int = xv
var y: Int = yv
var a: String = "test"
}

trait Debug{
    def debugVars():Any = {
        var i = 0
        val vars = this.getClass.getDeclaredFields

        for(v <- vars){
        v.setAccessible(true)
        println("Field: " + vars(i).getName() + " => " + vars(i).get())
        i+=1
        }
    }
}

var p : Point = new Point(3,4)
p.debugVars()
```

The ouptut should be:

```
Field: x => 3
Field: y => 4
Field: a => test
```

But compiler (I am using eclipse Luna) throws following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field Point.x to scala.runtime.BoxedUnit
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
  at Debug$$anonfun$debugVars$1.apply(<console>:21)
  at Debug$$anonfun$debugVars$1.apply(<console>:19)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at Debug$class.debugVars(<console>:19)
  at Point.debugVars(<console>:8)
  ... 53 elided
```

The problem for me is in the for loop `+vars(i).get()`, but I don not have any idea how to repair it. Any solutions or tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)), get requires the object on which the operation is been done.
Just change `vars(i).get()` should be `vars(i).get(this)` and you are good to go.

After making the change, you will get response in scala worksheet as

```
object s {
  var p: Point = new Point(3, 4)                  //> p  : dao.Point = dao.Point@7abdd25
  p.debugVars()                                   //> Field: x => 3
                                                  //| Field: y => 4
                                                  //| res0: Any = ()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From the land of "vars are evil..." :)

The `for` hands you each `"v"` on a silver plater -- no need to use `i` as an index.

```
trait Debug{
    def debugVars():Any = {
        val vars = this.getClass.getDeclaredFields
        for(v <- vars){
        v.setAccessible(true)
        println("Field: " + v.getName() + " => " + v.get(this))
        }
    }
}
```